# How can rebuild index in IOT(Index organized table)?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

**Dear all experts.**

I have IOT having 7 million records in oracle database, eventually iot use for fast access primary key but in my case, when i select primary key column it takes 5-4 seconds for select single column.
My query is:

> Select Emp_Refno from Emp_master where Rownum =1 order
>   by Emp_Refno asc;

I have also used **Sql Tunning Advisor** for optimize it and also get index suggest ion from SQL Tunning Advisor and also applied it, But in explain plan not seen this index and it takes same time after it.

Comment: Please provide the complete DDL for the table.

Comment: Create table Emp_master(Emp_id number,Emp_Refno number Primary key,Emp_name varchar2(50), Emp_email varchar2(50),isActive number,isDeleted number,Createdon varchar2 (20),updatedon varchar2 (20))  )
ORGANIZATION INDEX TABLESPACE Tbs_Employee;

Comment: This DDL contains a syntax error. Please have it generated by Oracle so there is no mismatch between what you think is the table definition and what it really is.

Comment: You can create similarly with iot table, actually i am using mobile device, i will post exact ddl on Monday.
But if you know about iot then you can create any table iot, apply multiple insert delete after create index on it, you can see your created index not work on it.

Comment: Actually i have already a database which use in application regularly from last 2-3 years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if the following query has the same execution time:

```
select * from (select Emp_Refno from Emp_master order by Emp_Refno asc) where rownum = 1
```

This is how I usually write top-n queries for Oracle.

Comment: Can i rebuild index on iot?